# write to text box from a thread in after aborting thread WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I use a consumer producer model and try to write to a textbox after aborting the thread, but it shows me several errors that I understood it can't done from the thread...
This is my bunch of code right now:

```
void LaunchConsumer()
    {
        while (myReceivedMessage.Count!=8)
        {
            try
            {

                var sampleFromCollection = samples32Collection.Take();   
                TempBuffer.RemoveAt(0);//Remove first object at TempBuffer
                TempBuffer.Add(sampleFromCollection);
                double TempFreq = (SampleRate *ZeroCrossRate(TempBuffer))/(2*TempBuffer.Count);
                //Zero = 387:392
                //One = 393:395
                int counter = myReceivedMessage.Count;
                if(12960.0<TempFreq && TempFreq<13040.0)
                {
                    myReceivedMessage.Add("0");
                    //MyTextBox.AppendText("0");
                    TempBuffer.Clear();
                    TempBuffer = new List<float>(Enumerable.Repeat(0f, (int)(SampleRate * BitTime)));
                }
                else if(13041.0<TempFreq && TempFreq<13131.0)
                {
                    myReceivedMessage.Add("1");
                    //MyTextBox.AppendText("1");
                    TempBuffer.Clear();                    
                    TempBuffer = new List<float>(Enumerable.Repeat(0f, (int)(SampleRate*BitTime)));
                }
                /*else
                {
                    myReceivedMessage.Clear();
                }*/



            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException) { }
        }

        myWaveIn.StopRecording();

        MyTextBox.Text = myReceivedMessage.ToString();//Here I get an error..
        Terminate();
    }


    void Terminate()    //Call this to terminate the consumer
    {
        consumer.Abort();

    }
```

Comment: how about the errors?

Comment: Just look at the "Related" section right of the page

Comment: So you say, "I am too lazy to read them. Someone do it for me".  **-1** BTW If you are interested in new technologies, why do you use threads. Tasks, async/await codes make life simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (!MyTextBox.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
{
    MyTextBox.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { MyTextBox.Text = myReceivedMessage.ToString(); });
}
else
{
    MyTextBox.Text = myReceivedMessage.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Hello. My message contains "0000000"(for example) but in the text box it shows: `System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]`

Comment: Yes, this is correct because your myReceivedMessage has List<string> type